# Python 2.7 Tkinter variable type incompatibility

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to use a value from an input window as a numeric value, but it does not allow me to convert a "string" according to the program (even if I just put in numbers) to a float value.

Short example:

Input comes from:

```
etiquette5=Label(eqGroup,text="Insert value for c")
etiquette5.pack(padx=10,pady=5,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
input3=Entry(eqGroup,width=10)
input3.pack()

inputList[0]=input1.get() #To be able to move the inputs from this method I put them into a global list
```

Input is used in:

```
def equationSolver(self): #For doing the math shenanigans
    a=float(inputList[0])#Error here. It is unable to convert the strings that it takes in via the input to float values
    b=float(inputList[1])#Error here. It is unable to convert the strings that it takes in via the input to float values
    c=float(inputList[2])#Error here. It is unable to convert the strings that it takes in via the input to float values

    X1=(-b/2)+(sqrt(pow(b/2,2)-c))
    X2=(-b/2)-(sqrt(pow(b/2,2)-c))

    globalList[0]=X1 #Once again, putting them into a global list for movement purposes
    globalList[1]=X2
```

Error Image [image]

The full code you can find here: http://pastebin.com/1Umug0ms

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance, Staggen

Comment: Have you done any debugging to verify that `inputList[0]` is what you think it is?

Comment: well, no. I do not know how to verify that (we have never ran debugging sessions in class). But at first the value is initiated with a 0 (you can see that at the top of the full script). So there it was an integer, but then it changed to a string from the input (it seems). Something happened at least?

Comment: You can temporarily add a print statement inside `equationSolver` to print out what is in `inputList`. I don't see anywhere where the entry is initialized to zero.

Comment: Line 8 and 9.

globalList=[0,1,2,3] #Global lists so I can move things between methods
inputList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `inputList` prior to the user actually entering data. Consider this line of code:

```
inputList[0]=input1.get()
```

This will set `inputList[0]` to the value that is in the entry widget *at that that moment*. If this is done in an initialization function (*any* function called before the UI is displayed), the value will be blank. When you try to use this later, you'll get an error since an empty string is not a valid number.

You need to delay getting the values until you are ready to use them.

Comment: full code is still here: http://pastebin.com/1Umug0ms
But I did define the lists before everything else, to make sure they became global so I could always access them.

However, the call to the inputList[0] is not in an __init__ method. It is several methods down into the class.

Comment: Ok, you've confirmed what I wrote.  You're resetting `inputList` before the user has a chance to enter any data (it's not in _the_ `__init__` method, but you're still setting the variable during initialization. The user won't have had a chance to enter any data by the time you call `input1.get()`.

Comment: but if I remove it from the top, then it says that the list is not defined when I first try to use it? The whole point of it was to get it initialized early on to be able to move it between the methods. Can I get around this somehow? Because I need to move the answer of X1 and X2 to the other method where they are going to be written out as the answer...

Comment: @Staggen: those are deeper questions that can't be answered in a comment. Stackoverflow isn't a discussion forum. It's designed for people asking a single question, and then getting answers to that question. It's not designed for long discussions.